# vim plugin csupport: How to change the layout of automatic header?

Tags: vim, editor, vim-plugin

How do I change the layout of automatic header in csupport for vim?
I looked at the template files under `c-support/templates/` directory, I have no idea about where they are defined.

Also setting custom macro using the syntax specified in [csupport manual](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-c/csupport.html#csupport-templates-files) does not add it to the header, do I have to make some other changes for the custom macro to be included in the header?

Comment: If you have an issue with a plugin, it's best to ask the author itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux, yes the header template is under template folder. To modify this, check on **template/c.comment.template**, change structure or add new information. To fill the value (AUTHOR, ORGANIZATION, etc), add it on **template/Template**. Check it.